# Will the iPad now come with EarPods?

Tags: ipad, ear-phones

Since Apple recently announced the new EarPods to go along with the iPhone 5, I've wanted a pair.

The only thing is I'm planning on buying an iPad in a few months, and if the iPad comes with EarPods I'm fine with a wait - it's not urgent.

So, will the iPad come with EarPods?

Comment: I love the ambiguity Apple has introduced. Which new iPad? "The New iPad" (the current generation, released model). Or, the new iPad (note the case change, the next generation that everyone is expecting them release next month, so says the rumor mill).

Comment: @JasonSalaz Or we could have no ambiguity with "the old iPad" (iPad 2), "the iPad" (3rd-gen), and "the next iPad" (yet-to-be-released), just like we do with the laptops.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The New iPad currently being sold on the Apple Store doesn't come with headphones of any kind, according to their site:

[image: New iPad "In the Box" screen capture]

So it seems unlikely that they'll start shipping them with EarPods, especially since the EarPods are already on sale.

That said, there's no way to answer this question aside from pure conjecture. Perhaps a future model of the iPad will ship with the EarPods.

Comment: I purchased a "The new iPad" a few months ago, and can confirm that list is accurate.